# Convert\Modify Air fryer from 120v to 220\240

Tags: voltage

Dash Compact Air Fryer

i wanted to ask if its possible and\or practicle to convert an 120v air fryer(1000w) to work on 220-240 outlet ?
it has a heat spiral and a fan (if it helps)
if more info is needed so please tell me and ill provide.

im not a pro in electronics but i understand basic stuff and can solder.

Dash Compact Air Fryer

sorry for bad english and thanks in advance :)

Comment: 240V->120V is possible by center-tapping and connecting the center to live and connecting both ends to neutral. You cannot do this in the 120V->240V direction. So, no, it's not possible if the device wasn't built for both voltages and has some provision to select it.

Comment: Adding an external transformer is the way to go. They do make those; they're not cheap considering that power rating you'll need, but cheaper than getting a new fryer most likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no it's not possible to "convert" a 120v appliance to run on 240v, except by replacing the 120v heating element and fans with 240v equivalents.

What is possible however, is to operate the device behind a [240v to 120v mains transformer](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=240v+to+120v+transformer&ia=products). Many exist, just find one rated for more Watts than the fryer (1,000W or 1kW). Such a transformer is likely to be heavy and expensive, but as a bonus, other devices will work with it also.

Comment: Ideally, 2x or 3x the capacity is a good idea. So if a 5kW transformer is available, just get one of those, and you shouldn't have to worry about it heating up too much.